# split file at delimiters, with file extension for content after each delimiter

Tags: bash, split, delimiter

I have data like this in `example.txt` :

```
line 1
line 2
delimA
line 3
line 4
delimB
line 5
line 6
```

I want to end up with three different files:

`example.txt`:

```
line 1
line 2
```

`example.a.txt`

```
line 3
line 4
```

`example.b.txt`

```
line 5
line 6
```

I can think of several ways to do this with long custom scripts, but I want to know if there are any bash utilities that would make this significantly simpler.

Comment: Originally, I was thinking of a python script because that is my main language, but one bash approach would be to make three different copies of all the files and then `sed` them in place. I'm asking the question because I want to learn new ways to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk you could do something like this:

```
awk '/^delim/{f=tolower(substr($0,length($0),1));next}{print > ("example"(f?"."f:"")".txt")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash solution. The result are files `example.0.txt`,`example.1.txt`, and `example.2.txt`.

```
number=0                                # output file number
output="example.${number}.txt"          # 1. output file name
> "$output"                             # empty output file

while read line ; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^delim ]] ; then       # delimiter at begin of line ?
    output="example.$((++number)).txt"  # next output file
    > "$output"                         # empty output file
  else
    echo "$line" >> "$output"
  fi
done < "$input"
```